# YII2 Bootstrap group menu

Tags: yii2, submenu, bootstrapping

I am new one for the YII2.0, in my requirement I want the group menu (see the below screen), I search in google, but I did not get the my need one.

[image]

Your idea and suggestion will help me more,thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use nav (Nav::widget)  in navBar

the code is from  this doc http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-bootstrap-nav.html

> ```
>       echo Nav::widget([
>       'items' => [
>           [
>               'label' => 'Home',
>               'url' => ['site/index'],
>               'linkOptions' => [...],
>           ],
>           [
>               'label' => 'Dropdown',
>               'items' => [
>                    ['label' => 'Level 1 - Dropdown A', 'url' => '#'],
>                    '<li class="divider"></li>',
>                    '<li class="dropdown-header">Dropdown Header</li>',
>                    ['label' => 'Level 1 - Dropdown B', 'url' => '#'],
>               ],
>           ],
>           [
>               'label' => 'Login',
>               'url' => ['site/login'],
>               'visible' => Yii::$app->user->isGuest
>           ],
>       ],
>       'options' => ['class' =>'nav-pills'], // set this to nav-tab to get tab-styled navigation
>   ]);
> ```

or

> ```
>   use yii\bootstrap\NavBar;
>   use yii\bootstrap\Nav;
>
>   NavBar::begin(['brandLabel' => 'NavBar Test']);
>   echo Nav::widget([
>       'items' => [
>           ['label' => 'Home', 'url' => ['/site/index']],
>           ['label' => 'About', 'url' => ['/site/about']],
>       ],
>       'options' => ['class' => 'navbar-nav'],
>   ]);
>   NavBar::end();
> ```

from this doc http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-bootstrap-navbar.html